# how to filter given value from being fetched from sql in php

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I'm having a hard time trying to do this.
I have this code here:

```
function submit_category_list()
{
    $sql_query2 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 ORDER by title ASC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql_query2);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result2))
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $catid = $row['id'];
            $catname = $row['title'];
            $catname = stripslashes($catname);
            $content = $content . "<option value=\"$catid\">$catname</option>";
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

This will fetch and display all the entries in the table categories, but theres one entry that I don't want to be displayed or even fetched, because I don't want users be able to submit content to that categorie, if that categorie appear in the submit form they will be able to submit content there...

**Edit:**
I found this code in the form validation file wich is the best approach to prevent the category submission, but i just dont know where to start or what to do:

```
// Check to see if the URL is banned.
         $array=parse_url($contenturl2);
          $domaincheck = $array['host'];
          $domaincheck1 = str_replace("www.", "", $domaincheck);
          $domaincheck2 = "http://".trim($domaincheck1);
          $domaincheck3 = "http://www.".$domaincheck2;


          $query = "select id from banned where (url = '$contenturl' || url = '$contenturl2' || url = '$domaincheck' || url = '$domaincheck1' || url = '$domaincheck2' || url = '$domaincheck3') && url != ''";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
            $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "Cannot Approve Submission";
            header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
            exit;
            }
```

I appreciate any help with this

Comment: specify the columns name you want to be returned rather than use wildcard ( * ) on your query.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering Dee. i dont want to filter columns from being fetched but entryes from that table. i need something like: if value "hosted" dont fetch.....

Comment: What's the point in such a jumbo indents? To make reading harder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your query to exclude that specific category (assuming your table has a `cat_id` column):

```
SELECT * FROM categories
  WHERE status = 1 AND cat_id <> the_id_to_exclude
  ORDER by title ASC
```

But make sure you check on submit too! Users can and will fake a GET or POST to specify whatever they want, so a check before insert is *mandatory*. (Along with all the usual SQL injection protections.)

Comment: Thanks Mat that might do the work, but now you are scaring me because due to my poor skils i dont know how to prevent that to happen. Can you give me some example how to secure the form?

Comment: Search this site with "[mysql] [php] sql injection", and sort the results by votes. Plenty of information is available on these topics here and on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do more than just not displaying that category to the user. A malicious (ie. evil) user might send that type of data to your submit handler anyhow, and therefor you should also add a security check when content is submitted to any category.

Though there are a few different solutions to your questioned problem, among them are:

- Change the SQL where claus to filter off on some column value of `categories` that you do not want.

  For example, filtering off all categories with the `title` "hello world"; `WHERE status = 1 AND title <> 'hello world'`

  filtering off by id: `WHERE STATUS = 1 AND id <> 42` (where 42 is the relevant id)
- Do the filtering part in your PHP (not really recommended, mysql is better at handling these kind of issues).

.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
  $catid = $row['id'];
  $catname = $row['title'];
  $catname = stripslashes($catname);

  if ($row['title'] != 'hello world')
    $content = $content . "<option value=\"$catid\">$catname</option>";
}
```